# SSIS power query source -> connection manager description

Tags: ssis, powerquery

Since excel source has constatnt problems with truncating either numbers or texts - can't get it to work properly with mixed data in one column, i've figured out Powerquery source would be the answer.

I managed to import one file.
Now i try to iterate over all files in the folder.

[image]

Problem is in Description of Connection manager - can I somehow use wildcards for all files ? otherwise it crashes with error for incorrect credentials.

[image]

As of connection manager - no problem as i can use expressions to use variables

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Power Query still on preview, very limited compared with all the functions in the for example Power BI desktop version.

In your case do the query using Power BI Desktop, select new source > from Folder, do the transformations and the copy and paste the code in SSIS PQY. In that way you don't have to resort using wildcards in the SSIS flow to iterate over files in the same folder.